# php maximum execution time displays 504 error even though the script is running

Tags: php

In my script I have defined the maximum time execution for inserting a database query using

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

However, after 5 minutes, the page will display 504 error and when I checked the database after 10 minutes I can see all the data has been inserted into the database but the page still displays 504 error. is there any way to hide the 504 page when the script is running ?

Thank you

Comment: use `phpinfo();` to check `max_execution_time` updated or not.

Comment: It is not the script terminating, it looks like webserver does due to a time out. Use some chunked header and transfer some data regulary.

Comment: 504 status code stands for **Gateway Timeout**. That means you have something between PHP and the browser. Do you have a proxy or a fast CGI process?

Answer (score 1):

The 504 Gateway Timeout error means that the server did not receive a timely response.
But the main thing is that, you have the maximum execution time set to 0, which means infinite execution time, so the script will run infinitely, so the browser can not receive the response.
The infinite execution time should be only used in CLI mode running scripts.

Comment: It is possible as I said in my comment of the question itself. Use Transfer-Encoding: chunked and send regulary (every minute or so) at least one chunk.

Comment: how to send chunks back when script is not yet finished?